# Android facebook login with sdk 4.0 returns to onCancel() the first time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm working with Android Facebook SDK 4.0, and when the user logs in the first time (when facebook dialog with permissions request appears) the return callback goes to onCancel() event instead of onSuccess().

Do you know why this could be happening? I tried everything for days, but i can't figure what is this.

Here's the code (I'm working on a DialogFragment class):

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

private void loginOnFacebook() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity()));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    LoginManager manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

    manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            mFacebookShare.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            if (com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("publish_actions"))
                mFacebookShare.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });

    manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here's my AndroidManifest file:

```
<application>
...
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by removing android:noHistory="true"
from FacebookActivity declaration in Android Manifest file of my application.

Comment: Hi I have provided an answer now. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have android:noHistory="true" in my FacebookActivity declaration
How to fix in this case

Comment: +1, I had a similar kind of problem. But facebook login was not working, when the app/device is in French language. when I removed this tag from the manifest, it is now working fine for me. Thanks a lot mate.